# How to Check Permission on List Using REST API in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Kindly suggest, how to check LoggedIn user permission on List using REST API in SharePoint.

Appreciate for any reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run a REST query against it, and if a 401 is returned, the user doesn't have access.